# Selecting by attribute using input file name in for loop

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, iterator

I have a set of feature classes with naming convention:
abcde_xxxxxxx_abcde.
I also have a shapefile, Mapsheet, with the field "MS" populated with values xxxxxxx.
I would like to loop through the feature classes and clip them using the Mapsheet shapefile where the attribute value xxxxxxx matches the input file name abcde_xxxxxxx_abcde (i.e. where the 7th-13th character of the input filename is the same as the MS field attribute xxxxxxx)

```
arcpy.env.workspace= "D:/Users/Temp.gdb/Unclipped_Poly_Select/"
select_polys = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*ALB_Select_Poly")
print select_polys

for select_poly in select_polys:
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ( "D:/Users/MS_20160704.lyr",
                                       "NEW_SELECTION", "[MS] =select_poly[6:13]")                                                                                         

arcpy.Clip_analysis(select_poly,clip_features = "D:/Users/MS_20160704.lyr",
                    out_feature_class =  "D:/Users//Temp.gdb/Clipped_Poly/""IHO1a_" + select_poly[6:13] + "ALB_ICP")
```

The error I am getting is when trying to select by attribute. I am told that attribute value is not valid.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Assuming the indentation of your code is correct (unlike the snippet that you pasted), your first mistake is using Python string slicing in SQL statement. I advise you to revise this part as follows and see the result: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("D:/Users/MS_20160704.lyr","NEW_SELECTION", "[MS] = '%s'" %select_poly[6:13])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to pass python syntax into a SQL expression.  This won't work the way you've done it.  Currently you're passing a selection query of `[MS] =select_poly[6:13]`, and not the actual value of your `select_poly` parameter.

You also need to tell arcpy to perform actions on a layer rather than a layer file (.lyr).  This can be done using `arcpy.mapping.Layer()`

Try this instead:

```
arcpy.env.workspace= "D:/Users/Temp.gdb/Unclipped_Poly_Select/"
select_polys = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*ALB_Select_Poly")

mylayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\Users\MS_20160704.lyr")

for select_poly in select_polys:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (mylayer, "NEW_SELECTION", "MS = '{}'".format(select_poly[6:13])) 
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(select_poly, mylayer, r"D:\Users\Temp.gdb\Clipped_Poly\IHO1a_{}ALB_ICP".format(select_poly[6:13]))
```

If your select value is `abcdefg`, then it will pass a selection query of `[MS] = 'abcdefg'` to the `SelectLayerByAttribute` tool, and the clip will output a new feature class called `IHO1a_abcdefgALB_ICP`

Answer (score 1):

I see syntax error both in `SelectByAttribute` and `Clip_analysis` . Please try this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace= r"D:/Users/Temp.gdb/Unclipped_Poly_Select/"
select_polys = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*ALB_Select_Poly")
print select_polys

poly = r"select_poly_feature"
## extract *.shp path from symbology layer
dataSource = r"" + str(arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:/Users/MS_20160704.lyr").dataSource)
base = r"base"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dataSource, base)
for select_poly in select_polys:
    output = r"D:/Users//Temp.gdb/Clipped_Poly/"+ "IHO1a_" + select_poly[6:13] + "ALB_ICP"
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(select_poly, poly)     
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_Management( base,"NEW_SELECTION"," \"MS\"= \'{0}\'".format(select_poly[6:13])) 
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(poly, base, output)
```

Both `select_poly` and `"D:/Users/MS_20160704.lyr"`, should be `FeatureLayer` , because both functions require it as input.